# Address is already in use after killing ports

Tags: node.js, express, centos, port

I've killed this port 8080 a lot of times with npx kill-port 8080
but I still get an error saying:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
```

Here is the code

```
const app = express()
 app.post("/dblwebhook", webhook.listener(async vote => {
    console.log(`${vote.user} has voted me`)
     }))
  
  app.listen(8080)
```

Am I killing the port wrong? (This is on my centos 8 vps)

Comment: You haven't posted any code that "kills" any ports - nor port-listeners.

Comment: `8080` is not the best choice of port to use for localhost dev/testing because it's commonly used by other services. You should use a random port number (over 1024 of course). Use `netstat --listen` to see what processes are listening on what ports.

Comment: and also don't forget that a restart of the whole system is a great port killer :D